# Select a random color, except certain colors

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm currently using this code:

```
Random randomColor = new Random();
KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
KnownColor randomColorName = names[randomColor.Next(names.Length)];
Color RandomColor = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);
this.BackColor = RandomColor;
```

I'm using this to generate a random color and set it to my background, but I don't want it to turn black.

Is there any way to take away black from the possible random colors?

Answer (score 8):

**Option 1:** Just use the Remove Method using a List:

```
List<KnownColor> namesList = new List<KnownColor>((KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)));
namesList.Remove(KnownColor.Black);
KnownColor[] names = namesList.ToArray();
```

**Option 2:** Only use a List. They have many more management possibilities than arrays do:

```
Random randomColor = new Random();
List<KnownColor> names = new List<KnownColor>((KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)));
names.Remove(KnownColor.Black);
this.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(names[randomColor.Next(names.Count)]);
```

**Addition:** You also can Remove all colors which are black but not named Black (e.g. ActiveCaption):

```
List<KnownColor> names = new List<KnownColor>((KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)));
foreach (KnownColor i in names)
{
    if (Color.FromKnownColor(i).ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb()) names.Remove(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and most efficient way to do this is:

```
Random rng = new Random();
public Color randomColor()
{
    Color.FromArgb(rng.Next(-16777216, -1));
}
```

This will create a random color without the color black. It works because the color class saves a color as an integer where black is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Following it's how I do filter colors (in this example I remove Black and White colors from my colors list) from KnownColor and return a random color:

```
private Color getRandomColor()
    {
        Random randomGen = new Random();

        KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
        KnownColor[] badColors = { KnownColor.Black, KnownColor.White };

        IEnumerable<KnownColor> colors = names.Except(badColors);

        KnownColor[] okColors = colors.ToArray();
        KnownColor randomColorName = okColors[randomGen.Next(names.Length)];

        return Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);
    }
```